# Видеокарта AMD R9 m265x и ее "приколы"

Tags: amd, видеокарта

Все в компьютере хорошо.Проблемы с производительностью наблюдаются только в играх(во всех(Даже в тех играх,которые раньше работали нормально)).Проблема решается так:
1)выключить дискретную видеокарту
2)зайти в игру
3)Включить видеокарту
Раньше такого не было,вот и не знаю,что делать,а температуры у этого ноутбука с начала эксплуатации были под 70-90 в простое(сейчас также(недавно чистил+переустанавливал windows))

Answer (score 1):

Было похожее с Nvdia,оказалось что драйверов нет(я windows переустанавливал до этого). Попробуйте с драйверами покопаться установить,обновить и т.п.

Ели ничего не произошло,то в настройки видеокарты -> и указываете какую видеокарту использовать(с Nvidia работает).